# Mostrar resultado en input date

Tags: javascript, html

quisiera saber como puedo obtener en valor que muestro en una etiqueta (span) y mostrarla en un input (date).
El codigo que utlilizo es este.

```js
var numero = document.getElementById('numero');

function calcular() {
  // la fecha
  const fechaactual = Date.now();
  var TuFecha = new Date(fechaactual);

  // dias a sumar
  var dias = parseInt(numero.value);

  // nueva fecha sumada
  TuFecha.setDate(TuFecha.getDate() + dias);

  // formato de salida para la fecha
  resultado.innerText = TuFecha.getDate() + '/' + (TuFecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + TuFecha.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

Comment: Se te olvido agregar el `id` al `input`

Comment: Hola @Cris223511.dev ya intente con tu respuesta sin embargo, no me muestra el resultado

Comment: Hola @iBokii, podrías mostrarnos que texto ingresas en el input?.

Comment: así como está y agregándole **id="numero"** al input, funciona, aunque no se si el resultado es el esperado

Comment: Claro @MarcePuente, en el input ingreso una cantida numerica, para calcular los dias apartir de la fecha actual, una vez que doy click, en el botón de **Calcular** automaticamente deberia mostrar la fecha en el **input date**, sin embargo no lo hace

Comment: Perdón, no había entendido que hace la función, y funciona ya la probé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**quisiera saber como puedo obtener en valor que muestro en una etiqueta (span)**

Para lograr eso debes obtenerla en JS con

```
document.getElementById('resultadoinput');
```

Y en HTML debes tener el elemento, en este caso lo hacemos de solo lectura

```
<p>Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultadoinput" readonly/></p>
```

(deben coincidir los id)

**como mostrarla en un input (date)**

Para lograr eso una vez que tienes la referencia al input, seteas su valor así

```
resultadoinput.value = fechaFormateada
```

Donde fechaformateada es el string que ya armaste con la fecha

## Código funcionando

```js
var numero = document.getElementById('numero');
let resultadoInput = document.getElementById('resultadoinput');

function calcular() {
  // la fecha
  const fechaactual = Date.now();
  var TuFecha = new Date(fechaactual);

  // dias a sumar
  var dias = parseInt(numero.value);

  // nueva fecha sumada
  TuFecha.setDate(TuFecha.getDate() + dias);

  // formato de salida para la fecha
  let fechaFormateada = TuFecha.getDate() + '/' + (TuFecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + TuFecha.getFullYear();
  resultado.innerText = fechaFormateada;
  resultadoinput.value = fechaFormateada
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numero"/>
<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
<p>Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultadoinput" readonly/></p>
```

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado, muchas gracias.!